# Expecting a specific thrown exception with Gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

I am new in using GTest framework. I Want to implement exception handling with one my tests. I've implemented a simple queue data structure equipped with finding a value within the queue. The implementation and calling of the function is below.

*queue.cpp*

```
LinkedListNode *CustomDataTypes::Queue::find_value(int value)
{
    auto found = false;
    auto current_node = head;

    try
    {
        if(current_node == nullptr){
            throw new std::runtime_error("Queue is empty");
        }

        // Sequentially check each node
        while (!found){   
            // Compare value
            if(current_node->value == value){
                found = true;
            }else{
                if(current_node->next != nullptr)
                {
                    // If not, then move on to the next node
                    auto next_node = current_node->next;
                    current_node = next_node;
                }else{
                    throw new std::runtime_error("Value does not exist in Queue");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "\n ERROR: " <<  e.what() << "\n\n";
    }
    
    // If correct, then return address of the node
    return current_node;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
// GIVEN: Queue class is filled with 3 elements
auto new_queue = Queue();
new_queue.push_back(1);
new_queue.push_back(2);
new_queue.push_back(3);
.
.
// WHEN: Startup
// THEN: Attempts to find non-existing element in queue
EXPECT_THROW(new_queue.find_value(4), std::runtime_error);
```

***Problem***

```
Expected: new_queue.find_value(4) throws an exception of type std::runtime_error.
  Actual: it throws a different type.
```

***Questions***

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Where should the `try` and `catch` statement be? In the `TEST` or `queue.cpp` scope?

Any tips or advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: In C++ you should throw exceptions without the `new` keyword. Try replacing                     `throw new std::runtime_error("Value does not exist in Queue");` by                     `throw std::runtime_error("Value does not exist in Queue");`

My guess is that the caught type by GTest is `std::runtime_error*` which doesn't match your expected type.

Comment: Also since your code is wrapped in a try-catch block that doesn't rethrow. It won't be propagated to the caller

Comment: @Nifil, thanks for the reply. I've tried both of your suggestion, I've changed the expected exception to `std::runtime_error*` which works with `new` keyword. However, without the `new` keyword, GTests notifies me that the function throws nothing.

Comment: Yes, because you catch the exception in your try-catch block when you don't use the new keyword. If you remove the try catch it would work. Depends on how you want your code to behave

Comment: It doesn't make sense to throw an exception if you catch it immediately in the same function. If your function *should* throw exception, then you don't need any `try`/`catch` - `EXPECT_THROW` in test will do. And any `try` should be at call site where this function is used (outside of tests checking this particular functionality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

In C++ you should throw exceptions without the `new` keyword. Start by replacing                     `throw new std::runtime_error("Value does not exist in Queue");` by                     `throw std::runtime_error("Value does not exist in Queue");`

As pointed out by @Yksisarvinen, try-catching an exception in the same block as it's thrown doesn't make sense. Either throw an exception and handle it in the caller's code, or have a default behaviour for when this error happens and don't throw at all.

So by removing the try-catch block from the function find_value and throwing without `new` your test will pass.